# Data from GET is returned differently then how the data is stored for map values

Tags: firebase-realtime-database

For example, here's how my data is stored:

[image]

When I do a GET for the data from this URL (using the [REST API](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/rest/retrieve-data)):

`https://<redacted>.com/maps/a6c00d68a95a5043374c1017b982d8f0b3009179/data/003_teleportIns.json`

The result looks like this:

`[{"sequenceNumber":0,"x":8,"y":3},{"sequenceNumber":1,"x":3,"y":14},{"sequenceNumber":2,"x":11,"y":15}]`

What I expected, was for the data to look like this instead:

`{"0":{"sequenceNumber":0,"x":8,"y":3},"1":{"sequenceNumber":1,"x":3,"y":14},"2":{"sequenceNumber":2,"x":11,"y":15}}`

Since I'm using [kotlinx serialization](https://github.com/Kotlin/kotlinx.serialization) to decode the data, the way that firebase returns the data results in errors when trying to decode.

Here's an example error:

```
Unexpected JSON token at offset 199: Expected start of the object '{', but had ':' instead
JSON input: .....":5,"y":7}],
"003_teleportIns":[{"sequenceNumber":0,"x":8,"y.....
kotlinx.serialization.json.internal.JsonDecodingException: Unexpected JSON token at offset 199: Expected start of the object '{', but had ':' instead
JSON input: .....":5,"y":7}],
"003_teleportIns":[{"sequenceNumber":0,"x":8,"y.....
```

So what gives? Why is firebase returning my data in an unexpected manor? If this is expected, please point me to the documentation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have sequential numeric keys in the result, the Firebase REST API (and SDKs) returns those as an array. There is no way to change this behavior, so what I usually do is prefix those keys with a short non-numeric string to prevent the array coercion. So `"key_0"`, `"key_1"`, etc.

Also see [Best Practices: Arrays in Firebase](https://firebase.googleblog.com/2014/04/best-practices-arrays-in-firebase.html).